# Am I able to use selenium.webdriver.Chrome to extract product information from ASDA website?

Tags: python, selenium, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am trying to use selenium.webdriver.chrome in Python to extract product information from groceries.asda.com

But if I go to a particular page (https://groceries.asda.com/shelf/everyday-family-cereals/2-for-4-cereals/_/3097456947) and view its source code in Google Chrome, I couldn't find the product names so I am unable to use methods such as find_element_by_xpath

Does anyone knows how to use selenium to extract the product names from ASDA website?

Tried xpath, css selector, all of them return NoSuchElementException

```
from selenium import webdriver

url = "https://groceries.asda.com/shelf/everyday-family-cereals/2-for-4-cereals/_/3097456947"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

nav = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="listingsContainer-0bd93fc4-888f-52c5-1c47-5679e4aab507"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/span[1]/a/span')

product = nav.text

print(product)
```

NoSuchElementException

Comment: Are you just trying to extract the product name? So for the page you linked to, you would want to extract "Kellogg's Coco Pops" for the first product?

Comment: Yes exactly, I just can't find "Kellogg's Coco Pops" in the source code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this approach - this should print all the product details using its 'alt' attribute

```
Products = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class=' co-product-list']//a/img")

print(len(Products))
for product in Products:
    print(product.get_attribute('alt'))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't know you can inspect the XPath with Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the inspiration. This works as intended. Thank u

```
Products = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='product-content']//span//a")

for product in Products:
    print(product.get_attribute('title'))
```